Semantic release of NestJS repo as a package
I have a NestJS repo, which just has 2 folders inside the src. Both of these folder has TypeScript class, which I have to use in multiple microservices. So rather than duplicating and creating a chaos, I though of putting them in one place and using them like libraries.
Now the problem is with semantic release, it is bringing in the whole repo rather than the dist folder. What am I doing wrong?
package.json
{
  "name": "types",
  "version": "0.0.0-semantically-released",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "readmeFilename": "README.md",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "files": [
    "dist/index.js",
    "dist/index.d.ts",
    "dist/index.d.ts.map",
    "README.md",
    "package.json"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "semantic-release": "semantic-release",
    "build": "tsc",
    "lint": "eslint",
    "lint:fix": "yarn lint --fix"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@semantic-release/changelog": "6.0.3",
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer": "13.0.0",
    "@semantic-release/exec": "6.0.3",
    "@semantic-release/git": "10.0.1",
    "@semantic-release/github": "11.0.0",
    "@semantic-release/npm": "12.0.1",
    "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator": "14.0.1",
    "@types/node": "22.7.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "8.11.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "8.11.0",
    "eslint": "9.13.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "5.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "4.1.4",
    "is-ci": "3.0.1",
    "node-fetch": "3.3.2",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "prettier": "3.3.3",
    "semantic-release": "24.1.3",
    "ts-node": "10.9.2",
    "typescript": "5.6.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "10.4.6",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "7.4.2",
    "rxjs": "7.8.1"
  }
}


tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@grocstock-types/ui": ["src/ui"],
      "@grocstock-types/api": ["src/api"],
    },
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"]
}

.releaserc
{
  "branches": [
    "main"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
    "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
    [
      "@semantic-release/changelog",
      {
        "changelogFile": "CHANGELOG.md"
      }
    ],
    [
      "@semantic-release/git",
      {
        "assets": [
         "CHANGELOG.md",
         "package.json",
         "yarn.lock"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "@semantic-release/github"
  ]
}

The GH action is:
name: 'Release library'
description: 'Release library'
inputs:
  GH_TOKEN:
    description: "GitHub token"
    required: true

runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
      with:
        node-version: 20.12.2
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: yarn install
      shell: bash
    - name: Build
      run: yarn build
      shell: bash
    - name: Copy package.json file to dist folder
      run: cp package.json ./dist
      shell: bash
    - name: Navigate to dist
      run: cd ./dist
      shell: bash

    - name: Release application
      uses: cycjimmy/semantic-release-action@v4
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ inputs.GH_TOKEN }}

